# Applying JS code to Meta Slider WP plugin elements

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I need to change things in the content of my slides, which are displayed by WordPress plugin "Meta Slider". However no matter how "late" my jQuery code is running, seems the slides are generated afterwards because they're not affected by my code.

I tried to run it within `jQuery(window).bind("load", function() { });` to no avail. Also tried to run it after `wp_footer();`, doesnt' work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried using `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {...}` ?

Comment: Yes, before trying the other options I mentioned.

Comment: I have heard that changing all instances of `$` to `jQuery` can solve this. Have never had to do this myself though.